# Does Crashlytics miscounts active users on Application Class?

Tags: android, crashlytics

If the call `Crashlytics.start(this)` is on `Application`'s `onCreate()` method, will it count an active user if something wakes up my application process?

For e.g. if I have a broadcast receiver or alarm, will it count as an active user if those wake up the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it does not count, but my answer is purely based on logic and common sense.

Crashlytics' recommended approach is to initialize the SDK in your `Application` class, so that crash logs (and every other type of info) can be collected as soon as possible in your app's lifecycle. When they introduced the `Answers` panel, my guess is that they figured out their way of determining what an active user is, based on a series of parameters and actions that indicates that the user is actually operating the app (which is, by the way, differs in every Analytics SDK provider, e.g. Google Analytics).

In short, **I don't think that the `Crashlytics.start()` method immediately counts for an active user**, because that would be just nonsense. But there's a quick way of determining that:

1. Create a testbed application that is fired up when you send a specific broadcast message
2. Initialize the SDK in the `Application`'s `onCreate()` method
3. Using `adb`, send the broadcast message and meanwhile keep an eye on the `Answers` page of Crashlytics
4. Wait for some time (it may take some time to register the hit): is the user being tracked as active?

You can try to reach Crashlytics support for this, but I'm not sure they are going to give away this information.

**EDIT**

Adding some evidence I've found [here](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/397163-session-length-for-answers):

> A session begins when the app enters the foreground and ends once the app is backgrounded for 30 seconds or longer.

This leads to believe (as I wrote above) that their way of detecting an active user does not rely purely on the SDK initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it should, unless it has a more complicated logic of some "actual activity" instead of just opening the app. [Application.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) is being called on the beginning of any Activity, Service or Broadcast of your app.

This is what is written in android documentation:

> Called **when the application is starting**, before any **activity**, **service**,
>   or **receiver** objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy
>   initialization of state) since the time spent in this function
>   directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity,
>   service, or receiver in a process. If you override this method, be
>   sure to call super.onCreate().

But keep in mind that if the app is already running the `Application.onCreate` will not re-run as it is already created.